# Ubuntu consumes more battery's power than Windows 8.1

Tags: battery

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 with Windows 8.1 dual boot.
I have noticed that Ubuntu gives 3hr and Windows 4hr battery timing.
Why?

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using, 14.04?

Comment: I am using 14.10

Comment: Okay, I've made some changes to my answer to fit 14.10. Intel p-state is enabled by default in 14.10 so I've included instructions on how to disable p-state (instead of enable). Disabling p-state offers more options for frequency scaling when using indicator-cpufreq. There is a slight loss of overall efficency for certain settings and certain tasks. See the benchmark link for more info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows has power management settings for your cpu set. You can install a cpu governor that will allow you to set the cpu to performance, or powersave:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

After installation, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type the command

```
indicator-cpufreq
```

An icon will appear on your system panel. Click on this icon and make your selection.

---

There are a few power management tools available to help you control power consumption.

First, laptop-mode-tools:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

To use laptop-mode-tools, execute the following command:

```
gksu lmt-config-gui
```

Next, an alternative to laptop mode tools is TLP. If you do decide to install TLP, you must first remove laptop-mode-tools as they conflict.

[Click here for more information on installing TLP.](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html)

Note: if you install TLP, I suggest using the hard drive setting "254" to minimize wear and tear to your hard drive. Also, if you want to use indicator-cpufreq, set the cpu "governor" to "performance". This eliminates scaling from TLP and allows scaling to be controlled by indicator-cpufreq. [See here for more info.](https://askubuntu.com/a/556937/167115)

[here for more info on laptop-mode-tools](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/install-laptop-mode-tools-164-with.html)

---

**The following is for intel users only.**

---

For more control over cpu freq. scaling, you can disable intel pstate. Disabling p-state will offer the options conservative, powersave, ondemand, and performance.

First, open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now, look for "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" and make the line look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"
```

Save the file, exit gedit, and execute the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot for the changes to take effect.

[click here for benchmarks and statistical use comparison between intel p-state and acpi cpu control including power consumption and performance](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_pstate_linux315&num=2)

[intel_pstate at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt)

[Click here for more info on intel_pstate.](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html)

**Install thermald:**

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

Reboot for the changes to take effect.

[click here for info on thermald](https://01.org/linux-thermal-daemon/documentation/introduction-thermal-daemon)

Comment: I've managed to switch from cpu_freq to intel_pstate, and been pretty happy with the performance so far:  On my system the CPU turbo modes seem to be handled in a more coherent manner than they were with cpu_freq and the power consumption is not notably different.