# Ubuntu 18.04 battery life

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery

I know there are many questions on this argument, but I want to be sure that the answer for old ubuntu version can be used for this version, so this is the question, how can I improve my battery life on ubuntu 18.04? I installed ubuntu in dual boot with win10 and I've noticed that ubuntu run more frequently the fans and the estimated battery life is less then win10. I've already switched to integrated intel graphics card and I've installed tlp, what can I still do?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte is compatible with tlp or are mutual exclusive?

Comment: for now seems they are working together and the battery is improved of 1 hour

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple power managers, and for a laptop, you may want to use `laptop-mode-tools`:

```
sudo apt install laptop-mode-tools
```

Per *linrunner*, author of TLP:

> ```
> "Conflicts: laptop-mode-tools" --> salsa.debian.org/MoonSweep-guest/tlp/blob/master/debian/control
> ```
>
> So installing laptop-mode-tools will remove tlp and vice versa. I would
>   not recommend using apt purge because users will loose their edits to
>   /etc/default/tlp (in case they want to reinstall tlp).

You can monitor/diagnose your power consumption with `powertop`:

```
sudo apt install powertop
```

Comment: This will not work with TLP: tlp and laptop-mode-tools packages are mutually exclusive.

Comment: some sources say it will... many say they conflict, I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: The package itself implements "Conflicts: laptop-mode-tools" --> https://salsa.debian.org/MoonSweep-guest/tlp/blob/master/debian/control . So installing laptop-mode-tools will remove tlp and vice versa. I would not recommend using apt purge because users will loose their edits to /etc/default/tlp (in case they want to reinstall tlp). Btw: I'm TLP's author.

Answer (score 32):

**This is how I get the best battery life with my Dell XPS 15 9570 (nvidia graphics) on any Ubuntu 18.04+ based system (Elementary OS, Mint, etc.)**

[image]

Install packages:

```
sudo apt-get install tlp powertop
```

Enable tlp:

```
sudo tlp start
```

Check that it's running:

```
sudo tlp-stat -s
```

Check battery drain watts with AC disconnected and most apps and browser tabs closed (give it a few moments to stabilise):

```
sudo powertop
```

[image: powertop drain]

Press ESC to exit (it takes a few seconds).

---

### Important for nvidia graphics

Using your onboard intel graphics when you're on battery should make a big difference.  However tlp will not power down the nvidia card by default when using your onboard intel because it expects another service such as bumblebee to do so.  Bumblebee doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04+ so tlp is the best option.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
```

Uncomment this line and set value to empty:

```
RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST=""
```

Switch to your intel graphics, restart and check power usage:

```
sudo prime-select intel
sudo reboot
sudo powertop
```

Note in future switching to intel or nvidia only requires a logout depending on your setup.

---

### Optional further steps (applicable to all machines)

Check if **--auto-tune** reduces your power significantly:

```
sudo powertop --auto-tune
sudo powertop
```

If --auto-tune made a big difference then go to the powertop **tunables** by pressing TAB a few times.  Anything you adjust here is temporary.  Test which ones make a difference in your power usage without causing any annoying behaviour such as sleeping external USB devices too quickly.  Now make them permanent by editing tlp config.  This requires some experimentation.

To edit tlp config and restart it afterwards:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
sudo systemctl restart tlp
```

Refresh powertop tunables page by pressing **r**.

Comment: +1 but I think you meant to say `prime-select intel`

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10: Command 'restart' not found.

Comment: Note that powertop needs to run for like an hour before you can use the --auto-tune feature or it will throw an error when attempting. Sometimes the error does not mention it, but generally it will say something along the lines of "not enough samples collected".

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet that your problem has to do with your nvidia graphics card running all the time, despite switching to intel graphics. That seems to be the problem for everyone running 18.04 Ubuntu and they still hasnt't fixed it...

More info:

- https://github.com/timrichardson/Prime-Ubuntu-18.04
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1765363

Comment: So what is the solution or work-around?

Comment: Ubuntu and Linux Mint 20 users are no longer experiencing this issue. I'm successfully using Intel Graphics after specifying "On Deman" in NVidia X Server Settings. Note, you can check if your Nvidia GPU is running with nvtop aka Nvidia System Monitor QT which has a debian package on their github.