# Dell XPS 9570 ubuntu short battery life

Tags: drivers, 18.04, dell, power-management, battery

I have an xps 9570 running 18.04 [Jackhack96](https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin) version. I have recently realized that my battery life was getting worse. Opening *powertop* I saw the following

```
Summary: 2274,6 wakeups/second,  0,0 GPU ops/seconds, 0,0 VFS ops/sec and 55,4% CPU use

Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  7.40 W     15,2%                      Device         Display backlight
  6.93 W    100,0%                      Device         USB device: Goodix Fingerprint Device  (HTMicroelectronics)
  4.05 W    214,4 ms/s     315,5        Process        [PID 4302] /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=10183710076499817192,527516098290
  2.34 W     66,6 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: wlp59s0 (iwlwifi)
  1.13 W     61,8 ms/s      71,6        Process        [PID 6379] /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=10183710076499817192,527516098290
  962 mW      5,3 ms/s     443,7        Timer          tick_sched_timer
  956 mW     46,1 ms/s      92,4        Process        [PID 2281] /usr/bin/gnome-shell
  703 mW     24,7 ms/s     137,8        Process        [PID 3808] /opt/google/chrome/chrome
  638 mW     38,9 ms/s       9,6        kWork          intel_atomic_commit_work
  585 mW     23,2 ms/s      89,8        Process        [PID 2131] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -norese
```

The interesting part is that seemingly the fingerprint sensor (which doesn't have compatible drivers with Ubuntu afaik) is drawing a fair amount of power. Is there a way to disable it completely? Running *lsusb* I get the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:5395  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:671d Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thank you!

Comment: info on JackHack - https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin     (*I didn't know what it was, looked at found this, a script that modifies a pre-existing Ubuntu 18.04, or an ISO with changes already made*)

Comment: I get 9+ hours on XPS 15 9570 by using this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078939/ubuntu-18-04-battery-life/1134726#1134726