# Disable CPU throttling on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: 16.04, cpu, cpu-load

I've tried disabling CPU throttling by following instructions from here:

[How I can disable CPU frequency scaling and set the system to performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523640/how-i-can-disable-cpu-frequency-scaling-and-set-the-system-to-performance)

No go :

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep MHz
cpu MHz         : 3823.671
cpu MHz         : 3706.929
cpu MHz         : 3900.039
cpu MHz         : 3812.117
cpu MHz         : 3897.117
cpu MHz         : 1666.664
cpu MHz         : 2421.039
cpu MHz         : 3900.039
cpu MHz         : 3829.781
cpu MHz         : 3039.679
cpu MHz         : 3788.609
cpu MHz         : 1250.960
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the CPU?

Comment: The cpu is 6800k

Comment: `6800k` is not a CPU model.

Comment: You can see it by `lscpu`.

Comment: Try TLP and http://askubuntu.com/questions/556894/tlp-dont-change-cpu-frequency set cpu to performance in tlp

Comment: `Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                12
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 79
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6800K CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               3499.078
CPU max MHz:           4000.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
BogoMIPS:              6936.70
`

Comment: Yep, http://askubuntu.com/questions/556894/tlp-dont-change-cpu-frequency worked (disabling intel_pstate) ! Thanks!

Comment: It is better not to disable `pstate` but to switch it to performance.

Comment: Even when using the performance governor, the CPU itself can backoff the pstate (CPU clock frequency) by itself, if the load is low enough. Don't worry, it ramps up very very fast when required.

Comment: Oh, and when you disable the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, the the CPU frequencies displayed are what was asked for, not what is actually given. The CPU itself will still be backing off under very low load conditions, even though what you see suggests otherwise.